# How to break numbers in SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose there's a column value:

```
 235698752
```

How do I break it like:

```
 2 3569 8752
```

How can this be done in a SQL statement?

Comment: you really should not do it on server side.

Comment: What are the rules for breaking it?

Comment: What's the data type on the column?  If you have to do it server side you may also end up having to cast it before it can be split up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option, also for SQL Server:

```
SELECT STUFF(STUFF('235698752',6,0,' '),2,0,' ')
```

Comment: Neat - I had not heard of the STUFF function before - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot, not sure if it's exactly what you want:

```
SELECT '[' + CAST(235698752 as char(10)) + ']'
, SUBSTRING(CAST(235698752 as char(10)),1,1)
, SUBSTRING(CAST(235698752 as char(10)), 4,4)
, SUBSTRING(CAST(235698752 as char(10)), 6,4)
, SUBSTRING(CAST(235698752 as char(10)), 6,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The same thing, in Oracle SQL using SUBSTR

```
SELECT 
SUBSTR('235698752',1,1) || ' ' ||
SUBSTR('235698752',2,4)  || ' ' || 
SUBSTR('235698752',6,4)
from dual;
```

Note this assumes a length of 9 for the number.